# Saving a MS Word document with consecutive numbering

Tags: vba, ms-word

@PKatona when I tried it in a real setting it overwrote some files. Upon examining  the code, I realized it was counting the number of files in the directory and saving as the next number (say 15th file in folder as 'ST14 TC15') instead of saving as the highest next number in the filenames (say there are only 3 files in the directory and the one with the highest ending is 'ST14 TC06' so the next file should be saved as 'ST14 TC07'. I hope that makes sense. But using some of your code I was able to come up with this: however 1) there must be a way to shorten it! 2) it works in Excel (where I made it) but 'Evaluate' line towards the end gives 'Sub or function not defined' error in Word!!

Thanks again

```
`Sub Largest()

Dim rng As Range
Dim dblMax As Double
Dim var_data(200)
Dim var_numdata(200)

'*   -   *   -   *
'to put filenames in a specific directory into an array
Dim MyFile As String
Dim Counter As Long

'Create a dynamic array variable, and then declare its initial size
Dim DirectoryListArray() As String
ReDim DirectoryListArray(1000)
Dim str()
ReDim str(1000)
Dim num()
ReDim num(1000)


'Loop through all the files in the directory by using Dir$ function
MyFile = Dir$("C:\HAPPY\SANTA\ELVES\*.docx")
Do While MyFile <> ""
DirectoryListArray(Counter) = MyFile
MyFile = Dir$
str(Counter) = Mid(DirectoryListArray(Counter), 8, 3)
num(Counter) = Evaluate(str(Counter))
Counter = Counter + 1 
Loop

'Reset the size of the array without losing its values
ReDim Preserve DirectoryListArray(Counter - 1)
ReDim Preserve str(Counter - 1)
ReDim Preserve num(Counter - 1)

dblMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(num())


Dim nextFilename As String
nextFilename = "C:\HAPPY\SANTA\ELVES\ST14 HP" + Format((dblMax + 1), "000")+    ".docx"

ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=nextFilename
ActiveDocument.Close


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This will find the last file sequence:

```
Dim filename as String
Dim seq as Integer
seq = 1
filename = Dir("C:\HAPPY\SANTA\ELVES\ST14 TC*.docx")
Do While filename <> ""
    seq = seq + 1
    filename = Dir
Loop

Dim nextFilename as String
nextFilename = "C:\HAPPY\SANTA\ELVES\ST14 TC" + Format(seq, "000") + ".docx"

Add your macro code here...
```

Comment: A 1000 thank you's @PKatona, it worked like a charm.

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure to make this as the answer,